# how to select the first value in a combo

Tags: javascript

I have a combo in my html, and sometimes I have to change the value to the first one using JavaScript.

```
enter code here
   <select  name="myCombo" id="myCombo">
     <option value="1">first option</option>;
     <option value="2">second option</option>;
     <option value="3">third option</option>;
     <option value="4">Other</option>;

  </select> 
   // resetCombo('myCombo')
```

And a JavaScript function with the combo as parameter:

```
function resetCombo(combo) {
      document.getElementById(combo).value =  document.getElementById(combo).get_items().getItem(0);
 }
```

But it doesn't work. Which is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update your method to

```
function resetCombo(combo) {
   document.getElementById(combo).selectedIndex =0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function resetCombo(combo) {
      document.getElementById(combo).value =  document.getElementById(combo).options[0].value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function resetCombo(combo) {
      document.getElementById(combo).value = document.querySelector('#' + combo + ' option:nth-child(1)').value;
 }
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function() {
  resetCombo('myCombo');
}
```

```html
<select name="myCombo" id="myCombo">
  <option value="1">first option</option>;
  <option value="2">second option</option>;
  <option value="3">third option</option>;
  <option value="4">Other</option>;

</select>
<button>reset</button>
```